# How to customize comment?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

For a specific type of file, want to define customized comment with below requirements.

1. Comment is start with `-comment`.
2. Comment content is surround by curly brackets `{ }`.
3. Only show comment content with comment color; `-comment` and curly brackets are displayed with default color.

If modify `$VIM/syntax/file.vim`, add below commands, `-comment { content }` will all displayed with comment color.

```
syn region  myComment       start=/\s*-comment *{/ end="}"  
hi def link myComment       Comment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing it:

1. rely on `matchgroup` clause of `:h syn-region`
2. adjust `start` and `end` patterns to exclude part of the matched things.

### matchgroup

As stated in help topic you can specify what highlight group should be used for the `start` and/or `end`:

```
syn region  myComment matchgroup=normal start=/\s*-comment *{/ end="}"  
hi def link myComment       Comment
```

Set it to `Normal` highlight group (which is the regular text).

### or adjust `start` and `end` patterns

```
syn region  myComment start=/\s*-comment *{\zs/ end="\ze}"  
hi link myComment       Comment
```

Here I am using `\zs` and `\ze` to denote where is the actual start (`\zs`) or end (`\ze`) of the pattern is.

- `start=/\s*-comment *{\zs/` will match `-comment {` at the start of the line but `\zs` tells vim that the next char is the first char of the actual match.
- same is with `end=/\ze}/`, where `}` is matched but the actual match is ended with the previous char.

Kind of, check `:h \zs` and `:h \ze` for a proper explanation.

[image]

Comment: For matchgroup method, '-comment' doesn't display with the same color as other -cmd; comment content is okay.
For \zs and \ze, comment content doesn't show with comment color.

Comment: what is the color of other `cmd? Use the same matchgroup=.

Comment: Now matchgroup method works fine when set matchgroup with the same color as other -cmd: `syn region  tclComment matchgroup=Special start=/\s*-comment *{/ end="}"`.    
Only curly brackets are also shown with Special color, instead of black. I'll just ignore this minor issue.
Not sure why \zs and \ze method doesn't work.